# sample GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8 depth texture error in some IOS device

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, texture2d, depth-buffer

I have a depth texture which is `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8`( or `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24`), and I can correctly sample this texture on some devices(iPhone5s iPad1), but fail with some invalid pixels. Following is bound gpu texture (the depth) and the format info captured by xcode :

[image: bound depth texture]
[image]

Note that I've clip the value into [0.999, 1] since the homo depth are mostly in the set. I am sampling the texture and clip the value in my shader also.

```
uniform sampler2D tex0;
varying mediump vec2 TexCoord0;
void ps_main()
{
  float bias = 0.0;
  lowp vec4 zb = texture2D(tex0, TexCoord0, bias);
  const mediump float mag = 20.0;
  mediump float linearz = (zb - 0.999) / (1.0 - 0.999)
  gl_FragColor = vec4(linearz, linearz, linearz, 1.0);
}
```

And this shader gives a wrong result on the devices mentioned above:
[image]

The device and driver info is:

```
Driver: OpenGLES2
Description: Apple A8 GPU
Version: OpenGL ES 2.0 Apple A8 GPU - 77.14
Vendor: Apple Inc.
Width: 2048, Height: 1536, BitDepth: 32
```

Any clues to this problem? Or some other debug suggestions?

Comment: If you force everything to highp does it work any better? I suspect you are skirting close to what the API guarantees in terms of precision. For example, zb is lowp which would only guarantee 1 part in 256 accuracy, but you then try to use in a computation in which needs at least 1 part in 1000 in your linearz computation.

Comment: @lsogen Yes! turns out the sampler2d needs to be highp for the depth texture to be correctly sampled.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. I've added an answer along this lines just so the question shows up as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relying on more precision than the API guarantees to provide. For example, the variable `zb` is `lowp` which would only guarantee 1 part in 256 accuracy, but you then try to use in a computation in which needs at least 1 part in 1000 in when computing the value of `linearz`.

Try increasing precision to `highp` to get above the critical precision threshold.

Comment: By "1 part in 256 accuracy" (which I've also read in the document), do you means lowp is like 1 byte accuracy? And "at least 1 part in 1000" means it needs a mediump?

Comment: Yes - the minimum guaranteed lowp relative precision is 2^-8 (it's effectively defined as a 10-bit floating point type, with one sign bit, one exponent bit, and 8 bits of mantissa).

Comment: ... but note that different GPUs may do different things with the precisions - the spec defines *minimums* not absolute requirements - so what works on one GPU may not work on another.